# Move images on a html 5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, svg

On a canvas I have several images

```
var img1=new Image()
img1.src= "imgsrc.jpg"

var img2=new Image()
img2.src= "imgsrc.jpg"

var img3=new Image()
img3.src= "imgsrc.jpg"
```

I then add the images

```
ctx.drawImage(img1,20,20);
ctx.drawImage(img2,40,40);
ctx.drawImage(img3,80,80);
```

But I am having trouble moving them individually. Is it even possible? For example

```
img1.moveTo(30,30);
img2.moveTo(50,50);
img3.moveTo(60,60);
```

Is there any alternatives if this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

There are quite a few canvas-libraries that allow "retained mode" elements on your canvas.

With "retained mode" you can do these functions on  **each**  image/element on your canvas:  move, scale, rotate, skew, animate, drag/drop, hit-test, and more!

Three popular libraries I can vouch for are: FabricJS, KineticJS and EaselJs (and there are other good libs too--not to leave anyone out!)

Here is a Fiddle using KineticJS that shows a draggable image on a canvas:  ---

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/bJuLe/

And here's some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      p{font-size:25px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Darth Vader is a "retained" image -- try dragging him around !</p>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.1-beta2.js"></script>
    <script>
      function drawImage(imageObj) { 
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          width: 500,
          height: 400
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
          image: imageObj,
          x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 200 / 2,
          y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 137 / 2,
          width: 200,
          height: 137,
          draggable: true
        });

        // add cursor styling
        darthVaderImg.on('mouseover', function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        darthVaderImg.on('mouseout', function() {
          document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        });

        layer.add(darthVaderImg);
        stage.add(layer);
      }
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        drawImage(this);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you draw something on canvas you cannot access \ change it in any way. the only thing you can do is to re-draw it on the new location (i.e erase it from the current location and draw it again on the new location)

If you want to achieve it use SVG

Comment: That is shocking. Can you recommend any libraries that would achieve this or will I have to use jquery